# How to host my existing APSNETMVC project in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, hosting

I want to host my existing ASPNET MVC project to azure.Can any one help me on this?
I have gone through this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/ but this tutorial explains, making space in azure while project creation itself. But i have developed my project already, now i want to host it in azure.!!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) -> App Services -> Add

Go through the dialog to create a new web app. After that, download the publish profile.

In Visual Studio, right click your MVC project, publish.
In the publish wizard, import the publish profile file you just downloaded.

====================

edit to add screen shots:

First, go to Azure portal to provision a new web app
[image]

Then, download the publish profile
[image]

After that, just import the downloaded publish profile file in Visual Studio web project publish dialog.

Cheers

Comment: if possible could you please explain with screenshots? i cant find the options in azure portal